# Query XML from database and access DOM

Tags: php, xml

The user creates a XML-file and stores it in the database as BLOB. Every XML-file gets its own row.

My script should query the Database and retrieve the XML-file of every row.

Every XML-file should be in an own php object and stored in an array. After that I need to access the DOM of every XML to display the data in an html template.

This is what I have got so far:

```
$stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT xml FROM table');

foreach ($stmt as $row)
{
    echo $row['xml'] . "\n";
}
```

It will output the information without the xml-tags. I wonder why. The problem is, I somehow need to access the DOM.

I read about

> simplexml_load_file

but it needs a filepath, which I don't have because the files are stored as BLOB in the DB.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [simplexml_load_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php) instead...

```
$stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT xml FROM table');

foreach ($stmt as $row)
{
    $data = simplexml_load_string($row['xml']);
    echo "<pre>".$data->asXML()."</pre>";
}
```

The reason why you probably don't see the tags is that you are echoing them out to a HTML page, which tries to interpret them as HTML tags.

Not sure about how your doing your `foreach` as it would more commonly be written as

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))  // Add correct retrieval method your after
{
    $data = simplexml_load_string($row['xml']);
    echo "<pre>".$data->asXML()."</pre>";
}
```

This depends on the API and if your using your own class methods though.